# r - How to use Aligned Rank Transformed ANOVA for 2x2 non-normal data?

Tags: r, anova, nonparametric, two-way

I'm a complete novice to stats and r so kindly bear with me.

I'm testing to see if the moisture content in two plants (p and s) is affected by heat (cold and warm). The 2x2 factorial data mandates a two-way ANOVA, but the residuals are non-normal. There are no repeat measures. There are 28 replicates for each of the four combinations.

I've tried to use the Aligned Rank Transform ANOVA. I've tried the method from "ART" package, and from the "ARTool" package. They give different results.

ARTool package method -

````
```
t <- as.factor(data$Temp)
v <- as.factor(data$Var)
a <- art(data$moisturea ~ t * v)
b <- anova(a)
```
````

This gives the result

```
`
> b
Analysis of Variance of Aligned Rank Transformed Data

Table Type: Anova Table (Type III tests) 
Model: No Repeated Measures (lm)
Response: art(data$moisturea)

      Df Df.res  F value     Pr(>F)    
1 t    1    108 79.21592 1.4593e-14 ***
2 v    1    108  3.10808   0.080733   .
3 t:v  1    108  0.89245   0.346923    
---
Signif. codes:   0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1 
`
```

ART package method

````
```
art.results = aligned.rank.transform(moisturea ~ Temp * Var, data = data)
print(art.results$aligned, digits = 4)
print(art.results$significance)
```
````

This gives the result

```
`
> print(art.results$significance)
             Sum Sq Df   F value       Pr(>F)
Temp     36072.3214  1 79.215921 1.459259e-14
Var       1840.3214  1  3.108078 8.073339e-02
Temp:Var   432.1429  1  0.892451 3.469226e-01
`
```

I can see the F values are the same, but the p-values are significant in one and not significant in the other.

I might also be doing something terribly wrong and have no idea about how to obtain/interpret the transformed results. Also, the significance values don't really make sense because -

```
`
> summarySE(data = data,
+           measurevar = "moisturea",
+           groupvars = c("Temp", "Var"))
  Temp           Var  N moisturea        sd
1 cool Purple Teepee 28  18.26173  3.428517
2 cool        Safari 28  20.26209 25.879418
3 warm Purple Teepee 28  15.82300 18.260486
4 warm        Safari 28  20.72589 36.158926
         se        ci
1 0.6479288  1.329440
2 4.8907502 10.034991
3 3.4509076  7.080677
4 6.8333947 14.020968
`
```

I really don't know what I'm doing and I feel like I'm going in circles! Please, if anyone could help that'd be really really really really great!!

Comment: A much sounder and more flexible approach is to use the generalization of the Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney-Kruskal-Wallis rank test approach: the semiparametric ordinal regression model, e.g., the proportional odds model.

Comment: Wouldn't Kruskal Wallis test not check for interaction? Also, I sort of HAVE to use ANOVA. My initial go-to was KW test when I saw the residuals were non-normal, but I'm sort of in a position where I need to use ANOVA.

Comment: What do you mean "have to"?   And Kruskal-Wallis provides a main effect test but is incapable to testing interactions.  ANOVA is a special case of regression, and Kruskal-Wallis is a special case of the proportional odds logistic semiparametric regression model, which handles interaction.